# SOLR - efficiently index millions of plain text files in bulk

Tags: solr

What is the quickest and most efficient way to index 10 million plain text files with SOLR (~ 300 gigs total)?

The files are located on the same server as the SOLR installation. from `solrconfig.xml`: mergeFactor is 25, autoCommit is 10000

currently I'm sending the files individually to /update with `curl` and `xargs`. This indexes about 500k an hour with high cpu usage.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: At least with SolrJ, the java client, you can send documents in bulk, reducing the number of http requests.

Comment: Can you post a status on what you ended up doing to resolve your issue?

Comment: @MikePurcell we changed the way the system worked so no longer stored files, just index their names.. sorry not much help